# How can i change text position on sweetalert box?

Tags: sweetalert2

I'm trying to place text to the left of my sweetalert box. How can i do it please?

Picture in attache, i would like to place text bordered to the left.
[Actual view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slgeE.png)

My script:

```
    Swal.fire({
    title:'<strong>Info produit : '+data.id+'</strong>',
    type: 'info',
    html: '<b>Designation : </b>'+data.designation+'<br><b>Unite : </b>'+data.unite+'<br><b>Prix : </b>'+data.prix+'<br><b>Categorie : </b>'+data.categorie+'<br><b>Sous Categorie : </b>'+data.sous_categorie+'<br><b>Fournisseur : </b>'+data.fournisseur+'<br><b>Statut : </b>'+data.statut,
    showCancelButton: false,
                    })
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
Swal.fire({
  html: '<div class="align-left">text aligned left</div>',
})
```

```css
.align-left {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using Boostrap +4 just wrap your html content :

```
<div class="text-left">Your html content here</div>
```

Comment: For Bootstrap 5 he could use `<div class='text-start'>Content Here</div>`